# Write the output from "for" loop to excel in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have the following piece of code:

```
my_list = ["US", "IT", "ES", "NL"]
for i in my_list:
    A = sum_products_by_country(world_level,i)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'value':A})
    Descending = df.sort_values( by='value', ascending = 0 )
    Top_5 = Descending[0:5]
    print(Top_5)
```

The "sum_products_by_country" is a created function which takes as arguments a data frame ( in my case is named "world_level") and a country name and returns  the sum by product for this country. Using this loop I find the top5 products and the sums for each country of my_list. Here is the output of this loop:

```
US          value
Product  


B          1492

H          455

BB         351

C          119

F          117

IT          value
Product


P           346
U           331

A           379

Q           190

D          1389

ES         value
Product 


P          3046

U3         331

A          379

Q          1390

DD         10389

NL         value
Product 


P          3465

U          3313

AA         379

2Q         190

D          189
```

I want to write this output in a excel sheet using :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('top products.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
Top_5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Could you tell me where should I put the code above in order to get the required excel document?
Is there also a way to get the column names(country,product,value) only once on the top in my excel document and not for each country separately? So I want something like this:

```
 Country   Product   value

  US        
           B          1492
           H          455
           BB         351
           C          119
           F          117

  IT          

           P           346
           U           331
           A           379
           Q           190
           D          1389

  ES         

          P          3046
          U3         331
          A          379
          Q          1390
          DD         10389

  NL         

          P          3465
          U          3313
          AA         379
          2Q         190
          D          189
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This script should help you:

```
#Create workbook object
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
sheet.title='Products by country'

#Generate data

#Add titles in the first row of each column
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value='country'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value='product'
sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value='value'


#Loop to set the value of each cell
for i in range(0, len(Country)):
sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=1).value=Country[i]#with country being your array full of country names. If you have 5 values for one country I would advise just having the country name in there five times.
sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=2).value=Product[i]#array with products
sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=3).value=Values[i]#array with values

#Finally, save the file and give it a name
wb.save('NameFile.xlsx')
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. What is the SSTC in the for loop?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to change that. It should be how long your arrays are. So if they are the same size, the length of any of them should do. If they are different sizes, I imagine you have to make three for loops. One for every sheet.cell.